# Benefits of using if statement with show/hide effects in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which I'm going to use for multiple HTML elements (of course with different id's):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".general").click(function(){
        $("#specific-1").slideDown("Slow", function() {
        });
    });
});
```

What is the difference when I add the `if` statement before running the effect? Is it slower? Does it prevent any type of errors?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".general").click(function(){
        $("#specific-1").slideDown("Slow", function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible"))
                $(this).css("display","flex");
        });
    });
});
```

*Note: I haven't tested the code. I suppose when you click on `.general` it's going to test if `#specific-1` is visible, if so, it'll set its `display` CSS property to `flex`. Let me know if there are errors via comments. Als*

Comment: Why not implement your suggested changes and test it yourself? Your first-hand experience would be more reliable than what you might see here second-hand...

Comment: The `if` condition is inside the callback and does nothing for the slide down, it just sets the display to `flex` when the animation is done ?

Comment: As pointed on the comments this :: *I suppose when you click on .general it's going to test if #specific-1 is visible* :: won't happen ...

Comment: True! @adeneo and DaniP.